# A/C works in neutral, stops cooling when in gear

Tags: ac, audi

I have a '08 Audi A3.

A month ago I noticed that the air conditioning was performing poorly and since I bought it used, I took it in to recharge the refrigerant, without any improvement.

When the car is in neutral, idling or revving a bit, the A/C fan starts working, and in a couple of minutes I have cold air blowing from the vents, as long as the gear stays in neutral. Using a mercury thermometer, the middle vent temp was around 8-10 C.

However, when the car is driven, the A/C stops blowing cold air instantly, until it goes back to idling. There is no indication on the dashboard that the A/C stopped working or is working on safe mode (or econ), like other cars do.

The mechanic could not find any pending fault codes.

This time we noticed that half of the refrigerant was lost, the low-side pressure was at 3, high-side was at 14 with an outside temperature of 26 C.

We recharged again the system with a UV leak detection kit. There are no leaks visible and I cleaned the AC radiator from the outside.

What could be wrong?

Comment: If you rev the engine when stationary and in neutral and hold it at high RPM does the AC stay on or shut off?

Comment: I gave it a try until 3500rpm, was working the whole time. Should I try with a bit more?

Comment: 2 minutes should do.\

Comment: It's an external control variable displacement compressor. Something is making the climate control unit/whatever controls how much the compressor is pumping destroke (reduce the compressor's pistons stroke and therefore the refrigerant flow across the system) too much when the car is being driven. The compressor, among other instances, should be destroked when you load the engine up and the cabin has been cooled enough, to provide a better driving experience, but something is just making the compressor cut the pumping action off too much. An OBD scan would be a great start.

Comment: You should get in touch with a mechanic/tech who is able to actually check how much your compressor is pumping at any time (particularly elaborate OBD systems, or electrical equipment which can sample the compressor control signal). The stroke valve and therefore the refrigerant flow is controlled by a PWM signal by the way.

Comment: After a few seconds of revving the compressor shuts off. I did an auto scan with VCDS again and this fault code came up; 00796 - Fan for Interior Temp Sensor (V42). Could this be the culprit?

Comment: It could well be or could well be not, but the interior temp sensor definitely plays an important role in interior temperature regulation so you'd best address it even if the problem doesn't lie in this fan. Remember, on your car the compressor NEVER shuts off. It's always pumping, a lot or nearly nothing but always pumping something around. Unless it seizes and breaks the torque limiter on its pulley, of course. So, once you start revving, it's destroking too much and not enough refrigerant is getting in the evaporator.

Comment: Forgot a thing: a too high/faulty pressure reading by the pressure transducer will make the compressor destroke too.